# Encode a string using PDO prepared statement

Tags: php, pdo

I have a string say '**Today's**' to be escaped and inserted into MySQL Database using PDO prepared statement. I have read PDO prepared statements automatically escapes and inserts strings. But It always getting inserted as `Today&#39;s`.Can anyone tell me what's wrong in my code.

```
$string ="Today's";
$sql = 'INSERT INTO table_name values (:friendlyName)';
$statement = $database->prepare($sql);
$statement->bindParam(':friendlyName', $string, PDO::PARAM_STR);
return $statement->execute();
```

I also tried using `addslashes()` from PHP. But no use

Comment: Your code works fine for me on PHP7.1, MySQL 5.6

Comment: Did you add `charset` into your database connection?

Comment: have you tried just passing the params into `execute()`?

Answer (score 0):

my issue was resolved.The issue is with filter_input() function which sanitizes input and encodes quotes.I have added flag `FILTER_SANITIZE_MAGIC_QUOTES` instead of `FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING`